# c++11 chrono unreferenced local variable

Tags: c++, c++11

When I use the following code to perform some action for 1 second, I get a C4101 warning from Visual Studio: warning C4101: 'highResClock' : unreferenced local variable. I don't understand why I get this warning when I use highResClock twice after declaring it.

```
chrono::high_resolution_clock highResClock;
chrono::duration<int, ratio<1, 1> > dur(1);
chrono::time_point<chrono::high_resolution_clock> end = highResClock.now() + dur;

while (highResClock.now() < end)
{
    // do something repeatedly for 1 second
}
```

**Edit:** It looks like the warning from Visual Studio is because std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() is a static function. The highResClock variable wasn't needed to access now(), even though that is the particular method I chose to use. Visual Studio seems to interpret this as a non-use of the variable. When I use the following I no longer get any warnings:

```
chrono::duration<int, ratio<1, 1> > dur(1);
chrono::time_point<chrono::high_resolution_clock> end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() + dur;

while (chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() < end)
{
    // do nothing
}
```

Comment: Remark: `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now` is a static function and can be used without an instance of `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`. I don't know why VS gives you C4101, but that could be the source.

Comment: FWIW, compiles warning-free [on GCC/coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b543c37fe327fcff).

Comment: Same holds for [`clang` with `-Weverything`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/198f8d25bf0093a)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using a static method on an instance of a class, which [causes this warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c733d5h9.aspx):

> However, this warning will also occur when calling a static member function through an instance of the class:
>
> ```
> // C4101b.cpp
> // compile with:  /W3
> struct S {
>    static int func()
>    {
>       return 1;
>    }
> };
>
> int main() {
>    S si;   // C4101, si is never used
>    int y = si.func();
>    return y;
> }
> ```
>
> In this situation, the compiler uses information about `si` to access the static function, **but the instance of the class is not needed to call the static function; hence the warning** [emphasis added].

The MSDN article also provides additional information how to get rid of the warning:

> To resolve this warning, you could:
>
> - Add a constructor, in which the compiler would use the instance of `si` in the call to `func`.
> - Remove the `static` keyword from the definition of `func`.
> - Call the static function explicitly: `int y = S::func();`.

Since you're using a standard class, you should resort to the latter, e.g. `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`:

```
auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(1);

while(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() < end)
{
    // do nothing
}
```

That being said, you shouldn't use a busy-loop to wait, there are other ways to do this (e.g. condition variables, or `std::this_thread::sleep_*`).